# Parsing response payload from rabbitmq queue

Tags: python, json, rabbitmq, devstack

I am getting a response in Rabbitmq message queue for various operations in Devstack (KILO version).

Now I need to listen to particular 'event_type' from the response.

Payload data is as follows:

```
\"event_type\": \"compute.instance.update\"
```

I have tried python code to parse the same is as follows:

```
def _handle_message(self, body):
    event_type = body['event_type']
```

Now the issues is that due to the slashes in it I am getting the error as follows:

```
2015-10-06 00:07:53,013 KeyError('event_type',)
```

I am not suppose to change the way how the responses are being sent.

I can modify the way how I am trying to parse it.

Please some one help me regarding this.

**Note:**

I was getting the code which I made working fine in previous versions of devstack.In those reponse data doesn't have thoses slashes.Now the main issue is with slashes.

Alternatively,
In simple words what I need now is matching the \"event_type\" exactly using python code.

Comment: Are you actually parsing the JSON anywhere? E.g. using `json.loads`.

Comment: Actually response which is getting generated was in Json format only.
But in my code What I need to do is check for the event_type in body.
that is from this response like this.
\"event_type\": \"compute.instance.update\"

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the KeyError ,it should definitely be the case that the key is not present in the dictionary.

In your case ,you are checking if the **event_type** is present in the body.You will have to even check json body to see if the "event_type" key is actually present as a child of the root node.The openstack event notification json format for oslo messaging is different and hence,try doing the below.

```
jsonbody = body['oslo.message']
event_type = jsonbody['event_type']
```

This should be the issue in most cases for openstack event  notifications parsing.